# How to add a UIButton in the background of other UI elements using Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiview, uibutton

I have to add a UIButton in the background of a View I already layout and position different UI elements on. I need to do this to resign first responder when user leave keyboard. But this button goes to foreground and I really don't know how to proceed. Any idea ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just needed to add the button in the top of the UI elements list in the Objects panel.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton is a subclass of UIview You have a UIView in place now change its class from inspector, and make the style default so it looks like a plain view but with  other controls inside it(as it is basically a view ). Wire it and use it

Regards,
Jackson Sunny Rodrigues

Comment: I need to use Touch Up Inside event on the button. Do you think changing my button class to a UIView will fix the issue ?

Comment: I guess so. If that wont work Replace the base view with UIButton. I dont have a mac with me now to confirm. Feel free to use trial and error method  It would help you solve later

Comment: Well, I just need to send the button in the background. Thx anyway for helping